# Add annotation color bar to ggplot or ggvis barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, plotly, ggvis

Does anyone know how to add an annotation color bar to a `ggplot` or `ggvis/plotly/... barplot`?

An example would be like "Heatmap 1" below, with a color bar (blue and red) representing sample information as type a or type b:

[image: An example of adding annotation color bar]

Comment: what have you tried so far? How about [showing some effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) or maybe a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score -1):

If you use the `type a/type b` variable for the `fill` aesthetic you will get colored bars and a legend.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))
ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome, fill=trt)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]